# Understanding how to use the factorial function in c++

Tags: c++, factorial

I have this code which works out the factorials for all integers between 0 and 9.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int factorial(int n)
{
    int result = 1;
    if ( n > 0) {
        do {
        result *= n;
        --n;
      } while (n > 1);
    }
    else if ( n < 0) {
       cout << "Error in argument \targument = " <<
        n << "\n";

    }
    return result;
}
    int main()
    {
    for (int i=0 ; i < 10; ++i)
        cout << i << "! = "<< factorial(i) << "\n";
    return 0;

}
```

I understand that the "for loop" in the `int main` section tells us for which integers to work out the factorials for. 
I understand that the "else if" section tells us that if we input an integer less than 0, we get an error.
However I do not understand this part of the code.

```
        if ( n > 0) {
            do {
            result *= n;
            --n;
```

What does this part of the code do?

Also why is n being decremented `--n;`? I am a little confused because the way I see it, if n > 0 and you decrement by saying --n, surely that will mean n < 0 and you will just get an error because of `else if`?

Comment: Do you know what "factorial" means? (Multiply together all the numbers 1..n inclusive).  Do you know what the C operator `--n` means?  (Subtract **one** from n).  Given those basics, it should be hard to not understand the code you're asking about.

Comment: Don't forget the condition for the loop.

Comment: Rereading your post, I almost wonder if you know what "decremented" means.  It does not mean "negated".  So your idea that `--n` would give a result `n<0` from `n>0` is incorrect.

Comment: Out of interest, why is this question being down voted? For future reference, how could I improve it?

Comment: @Aljabra: Just a guess here, but someone probably thought the question "does not show any research effort", which is part of the pop-up message if you hover the cursor on top of the down-vote button. But it wasn't me, so I can't know for sure.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> What does this part of the code do?

That is the actual calculation of the factorial value (e.g. `4! = 24`).

> Also why is n being decremented --n;?

Because it has to go from the number you want to calculate the factorial for down to zero. For example, "four factorial" (written `4!`) means:

```
4! = 4 * 3!
 3! = 3 * 2!
  2! = 2 * 1!
   1! = 1 * 0!
    0! = 1     (by definition)
   1! = 1 * 1
  2! = 2 * 1 * 1
 3! = 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
4! = 4 * 3 * 2 * 1 * 1
   = 24
```

Therefore, you need to decrement your way down to `0!` from `n`, whatever the value. Notice also that this is a *recursive* definition.

> I am a little confused because the way I see it, if n > 0 and you decrement by saying --n, surely that will mean n < 0

Wrong. `--n` is shorthand for subtracting one, or `n = n - 1;`. It does *not* mean negation/opposite of `n`, or `n = -n;`.

Answer (score 0):

The `do-while` loop is the very substance of the factorial algorithm (do you know what factorial does?). Secondly, once program enters `if(n > 0)` branch, control flow doesn't even consider entering `else if(n < 0)` after that. Instead, it continues with `return result;`.

Nevertheless, `n` won't be negative after the `do-while` is done. It'll be `0`.